# OneSignal - While building for watchOS, no library for this platform was found

Tags: xcode, onesignal, watchos

I'm trying to add OneSignal iOS SDK to my Project (which has a companion Watch App), and I'm getting the following error while trying to run the build:

```
While building for watchOS, no library for this platform was found in '/Users/xxxxxxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xxxxxxxxx/SourcePackages/artifacts/OneSignalXCFramework/OneSignal.xcframework'.
```

I've searched high and low and can't seem to find out why this is happening. Anyone have insight into what's causing this?

Comment: Did you found solution for this issue? I have similar issue like you mention in your question.

Comment: same issue and no idea so far :(